# SQL server variable of table type

Tags: sql-server

Can we declare variable of table type in SQL server like we are declaring in C#

```
DataTable dt= new DataTable();
```

If yes 
So how can we fill this variable from select statement?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Not sure why you wouldn't just Google this, theres literally thousands of good examples already.

Comment: I want make a function by sending select statement it must return those column which I choose it..

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

> Can we declare variable of table type in SQL server?

Yes , you can .

> So how can we fill this variable from select statement ?

Like this exemple :

```
DECLARE @K TABLE (
ID INT NOT NULL ,
P VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @K SELECT * FROM Test;
SELECT * FROM @K;
```

If you want `function` that return a `table`, Please [read this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx) first , then try to describe your issue as well.